# upload data sets always fail in GoogleColab,as below graph show

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

[image: upload always fail...]

upload data sets always fail in GoogleColab,this is a 150MB data set(csv file)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that is is due to local network conditions.

Try uploading the data to google drive first and then access it from there.

Here is the code snippet on how to do that (look for complete example [here](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=KHeruhacFpSU))

```
# Download the file we just uploaded.
#
# Replace the assignment below with your file ID
# to download a different file.
#
# A file ID looks like: 1uBtlaggVyWshwcyP6kEI-y_W3P8D26sz
file_id = 'target_file_id'

import io
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload

request = drive_service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
downloaded = io.BytesIO()
downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(downloaded, request)
done = False
while done is False:
  # _ is a placeholder for a progress object that we ignore.
  # (Our file is small, so we skip reporting progress.)
  _, done = downloader.next_chunk()

downloaded.seek(0)
print('Downloaded file contents are: {}'.format(downloaded.read()))
```